# JS: temporarily disable page rendering (possible?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I'm tryin to sort a big html table using JS. It takes a lot of cpu% to rearrange all the rows of this table. I think the big part of this problem is: every time my script moves a pair of rows, the browser starts refreshing the table

So, I'm searching for any way to temporarily tell the browser something like "wait, I'm sorting this table, dont waste CPU for rendering until I'll finish, plz?"

Basically, I need something lke "Memo1.lines.beginupdate / Memo1.lines.endupdate" in delphi >.<

Comment: that api doesn't exist in javascript in the browser. consider doing something like reach and a virtual dom.

Comment: You can either clone the table, sort it, and replace the original one, or detach the original, sort it, and then re-attach it.

Comment: Don't sort the table, sort the data, then render the table based on the data. Separate the concerns of data and presentation of that data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable most of the background rendering by disabling displaying of the parent element. Since the parent element is not displayed, client's renderer has nothing to render and also does not recompute sizes. Be aware that when you are updating the content, you will loose focus if it was present wihtin the parent Element.

To achieve something like `Memo1.lines.beginupdate` and  `Memo1.lines.endupdate` use this:

```
originalStyleDisplay = myMemo1Div.style.display;
myMemo1Div.style.display = 'none';
try {
  mySorting();
} catch() { }
myMemo1Div.style.display = originalStyleDisplay;
```

Answer (score 0):

alert(string) stops rendering, and not asyncronous calls, but not loading. You may prompt "too many cells to load, please wait" you may got the desired behavior.
note that, in order to work, string should be a non empty string after trim so a white space is not valid.